# Categorial grammar, Is 'leg' an adjective in 'skipping leg days'

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, noun-phrases

I am working on CCG (combinatory categorial grammar), which assigns categories to words.

So I was wondering if 'leg' is adjective, or just another noun in the phrase "skipping leg days". Or is "leg day" a noun phrase by itself? I mean do they combine to become "leg days", or "leg days" is already a form?

CCG would give leg a 'N' tag, and days a 'NP\N'. Meaning, days need a NOUN to its left to combine and become a NOUN PHRASE, that slash in between implies us this. A background info about this combinator is below;

```
Y : a X\Y : f  ⇒  X : fa         (Backward Application : <)
```

```
leg    days
N      NP\N
-----------<
leg days
NP
```

Comment: What is a "leg day"?

Comment: Leg day is a day in which you work the lower half of your body at the gym :))

Comment: Perhaps "leg" is an adjective in the phrase "leg training day", which is usually abbreviated to just "leg day".

Comment: "Leg" is a noun functioning as a modifier in the noun phrase "leg day". What else could it possibly be?

Comment: @nnnnnn No, it is still a noun. When you want to use **transitive** nonfinite clauses like *to train (the) legs* or *training (the) legs* attributively, you move the object before the verb and out it in the singular like almost all other attributive nouns do, and also usually hyphenate it.

Comment: can you write this as an answer so that I can accept it please @tchrist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **leg day**, *leg* is a noun and *day* is a noun. *Leg* is an [attributive noun](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012) (ThoughtCo) or noun adjunct in this noun phrase; it describes the kind of *day*.

Attributive nouns are commonly used with other nouns to form noun phrases in English. You can even form further noun phrases by using a noun phrase as an attributive noun: **Business ethics** uses **business** as an attributive noun; **business ethics class** uses **business ethics** as an attributive noun phrase. So you could talk about your **leg day schedule**, or your **leg day routine**. It's not hard to generate sentences with multiple noun phrases formed in this way:

> After my **business ethics class**, I took my **sports car** to the **branch office**, where I met my **Human Resources coworkers** for **Taco Tuesday margaritas**.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, “Leg” would be considered an adjective as it’s being used in that sentence even though it’s a noun.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm

Comment: How can it be an adjective? It's a noun function as a modifier of "day". Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective, you know!

Comment: Yes. Even though it's a noun, in this phrase, It's *considered* an adjective or it's *acting as* an adjective. It's assuming an adjectival role.

Comment: No, it's not considered an adjective: it's assuming a **modifier** role. This is precisely why it is so important to distinguish category (part of speech, like noun verb adjective etc.) and function  (subject, object, modifier etc.)

Comment: +1 for the link, so as far as I understood it should get a noun tag in a categorial grammar.

Comment: Notice the scare quotes in 'In that case, the first noun "acts as" an adjective' in the link. This indicates an etic (non-technical-term) usage, where a grammarian would be looking for a well-defined usage. Read '  "acts as" an adjective' here as 'is fulfilling a premodifier role like an attributive adjective, seems to be behaving exactly like an adjective, but is considered by most if not all grammarians still to be a noun for reasons E Lang Undergrads have to strive to understand'.